# Unable to get all ids from a string due to being truncated and appended with '...' elipses

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript

[image]

this.activityIdsForTracker stores the Ids of all checked Activities selected by the user. When the user clicks "Save", Event_Activity_Checkbox_Tracker__c is updated with list of Activity Ids on the object. This works perfectly for up to 10 Ids. When user selects 11 or more, Event_Activity_Checkbox_Tracker__c (long text, 10,000 char) only ever stores max 10 Ids. 10 Ids comes out to about 200 characters. So if the user checks 11 Ids and clicks Save... when they refresh the page, only the first 10 will still be checked.

In the JS below...
console.log('save act: ',act);
... prints out ALL selected Ids as expected

In the Apex...
System.debug('*** activityIdsForTracker: '+activityIdsForTracker);
... prints the following output. Where is the elipses ('...') coming from here?

```
13:35:30:008 USER_DEBUG [25]|DEBUG|*** activityIdsForTracker: (a1t55000002HfeoAAC, a1t55000002HfepAAC, a1t55000002HfeqAAC, a1t55000002HferAAC, a1t55000002HfesAAC, a1t55000002Hff9AAC, a1t55000002HffAAAS, a1t55000002HffBAAS, a1t55000002HffCAAS, a1t55000002HffDAAS, ...)
```

Apex

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void updateEventActivityCheckboxTracker(
    String siteSurveyId, String[] activityIdsForTracker) {

  System.debug('*** activityIdsForTracker: '+activityIdsForTracker);

  Site_Survey__c siteSurvey = [SELECT Id, Event_Activity_Checkbox_Tracker__c
                             FROM Site_Survey__c 
                             WHERE Id = :siteSurveyId];

  siteSurvey.Event_Activity_Checkbox_Tracker__c = 
    activityIdsForTracker.toString().remove('(').remove(')').remove(' ').remove('...');
  update siteSurvey;
}
```

JS

```
saveCheckboxState() {

  const SUCCESSEVENT = new ShowToastEvent({
    title: 'Saved',
    message: 'Your checklist has been saved.',
    variant: 'success',
  });
  this.dispatchEvent(SUCCESSEVENT);

  this.activityIdsForTracker = [...this.template
                              .querySelectorAll('lightning-input')]
                              .filter(element => element.checked)
                              .map(element => element.dataset.id);
  let act = [...this.template
    .querySelectorAll('lightning-input')]
    .filter(element => element.checked)
    .map(element => element.dataset.id);
  console.log('save act: ',act);

  updateEventActivityCheckboxTracker(
    {siteSurveyId:this.siteSurveyId, 
     activityIdsForTracker:this.activityIdsForTracker, 
     status:'submitted:'});
```

}

Comment: act variable is only here to print to console. this.activityIdsForTracker only returns an unreadable proxy object to the console.

Comment: What's the actual problem? Is this causing errors? What isn't working?

Comment: Event_Activity_Checkbox_Tracker__c is missing any Ids beyond the first 10 Ids. So it isn't saving the state of ALL selected checkboxes. So those checked boxes aren't saved after page refresh. @NickCook

Comment: the ellipses is just the debug log truncating the display (it won't display all the characters). You can verify that by doing a system.debug() within a for loop of the array to see it has them all. See this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253854/developer-console-suddenly-truncating-system-debug-output) and [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253381/system-debug-messages-get-trimmed/253774#253774)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the Apex... System.debug('*** activityIdsForTracker: '+activityIdsForTracker); ... prints the following output. Where is the elipses ('...') coming from here?

The ellipsis is a bit of a red herring. It's just the debug log truncating what's displayed.  You can verify this by iterating over the list in a for loop.

e.g.

```
for(String thisId : activityIdsForTracker) {
    System.debug(thisId);
}
```

For more information:  [Developer Console suddenly truncating System.Debug output](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253854/developer-console-suddenly-truncating-system-debug-output)

I don't know what you're trying to do, but i think you're trying to store a list of Ids in the `Event_Activity_Checkbox_Tracker__c` field.

Try replacing

```
siteSurvey.Event_Activity_Checkbox_Tracker__c = activityIdsForTracker.toString().remove('(').remove(')').remove(' ').remove('...');
```

with

```
siteSurvey.Event_Activity_Checkbox_Tracker__c = String.join(activityIdsForTracker, ',');
```

Comment: You're spot on. This is the problematic line. .toString in fact truncates with the elipses here:   siteSurvey.Event_Activity_Checkbox_Tracker__c = 
    activityIdsForTracker.toString().remove('(').remove(')').remove(' ').remove('...');

Comment: Trying join now

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks a lot @Nick Cook